# Probability of winning the election

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

Suppose you do a poll to one hundred people. 52% of the people say that will vote for candidate A and 48% of the people say that will vote for candidate B. What is the probability that candidate B wins the election?

A little lost on how to begin this one, any help would be great. I was thinking that I could use binomiial distribution but I'm not sure

Comment: How large is the electorate? If there are 101 voters in total (and we assume everyone answers truthfully), the chance of candidate B winning would appear to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to assume the $100$ people are a random sample of a very large electorate.  You should have a formula for the standard deviation of a sample mean.  Figure out how many standard deviations you are away from $B$ having $50.0001\%$ of the electorate.  Now use your z-score table to find the answer.